# Share a variable from JS and LESS in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, less

I have a website, and I now need to do some changes for mobile.

I was about to use the media query in order to apply css to those smaller div.

`@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {`

But in the code, I also need to change the content of some array (that draw some layout etc...) based on the size of the screen.

Now, I could do 2 variables,

one in less `@mobileSize: 320`
one in js (constant) `mobileSize = 320`

But I wonder if there is a way to share the same variable for LESS and JS, so There is only 1 place where I could put those variables.

Thanks

Comment: You can use [angular/cdk layout](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview). It allows you to select a css class based on an observable injected in typescript.

Answer (score 1):

*I believe that @julianobrasil is correct in suggesting an existing solution, if you want to save time long term!*

However, if you really want to do it this way here are two suggestions:

Using a JSON file:

Define your variables in a json file and import the file in LESS and JS. You will need to use a loader to load json into less, I haven't done this myself but this should work [less-json-import-loader](https://github.com/pigcan/less-json-import-loader)

Export the value in your CSS and read it in JS:

You can use `getComputedStyle` to read css values in JS. [Here's a post showing how to do it for SASS](https://css-tricks.com/making-sass-talk-to-javascript-with-json/) but the principle should be the same in LESS too.